# How to enable a securityPolicy for all the replicas of an external global load balanced backend service in K8s?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-armor, gloo

I have a `backendConfig` that has a securityPolicy attached. And I have `gloo` configuration that defines `gatewaySettings`, `horizontalPodAutoscaler` (with min replicas of 3), `kind`, and `service`.

```
horizontalPodAutoscaler:
        apiVersion: "autoscaling/v1"
        minReplicas:  3
        maxReplicas: 100
kind:
      deployment:
        replicas: 3
    # Configs needed to get the L7 Google External Cloud Load Balancer setup in the "netstack" Helm chart.
    service:
      type: NodePort
      httpsNodePort: 30443
      extraAnnotations:
        cloud.google.com/neg: '{ "exposed_ports":{ "443":{"name": "<name of the config>"} } }'
        cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"https":"HTTP2"}'
        cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "<name of the config>"}'
```

There are 4 backend-services when I execute the command `gcloud compute backend-services list` and only one of them has the securityPolicy attached, after I execute the `describe` API.

Why don't all the `backendServices` have the `securityPolicy` attached and is `gloo` config creating those services?

Comment: Applying the Cloud Armor policy to each backend through gcloud commands
will apply to only one backend, once check this [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-armor-setup-and-configuration-on-gke-hosted-application-9fe8847a0c0f).